# Not getting REST WCF BadRequest error message in .NET 3.5

Tags: json, wcf, .net-3.5, fiddler, bad-request

I have a REST WCF application developed in .NET 3.5.

To check for invalid request url like say for example missing parameters, etc. I am using a class which implements the "IErrorHandler" interface. So inside that class I have this section of code which is supposed to generate a BadRequest error code and message :

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
        {
            ExceptionHelper.HandleException(error, Severity.Error);
            StatusResponseBE statusResponseEntity = new StatusResponseBE();
            statusResponseEntity.Code = STATUS_CODE_FAIL;
            statusResponseEntity.Message = "Failed to perform requested operation";
            statusResponseEntity.Errors = new ErrorResponseBECollection();

            if (error is SerializationException || error is InvalidOperationException)
            {
                statusResponseEntity.Errors.Add(new ErrorResponseBE()
                {
                    Code = EX_INVALID_REQUEST_CODE,
                    Description = "Invalid Request"
                });
                fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, string.Empty, statusResponseEntity, new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(StatusResponseBE)));
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                statusResponseEntity.Errors.Add(new ErrorResponseBE()
                {
                    Code = EX_INTERNAL_ERROR_CODE,
                    Description = "Internal Error"
                });
                fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, string.Empty, statusResponseEntity, new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(StatusResponseBE)));
                fault.Properties.Add(WebBodyFormatMessageProperty.Name, new WebBodyFormatMessageProperty(WebContentFormat.Json));
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                return;

            }

        }
```

But when I am hitting my WCF service with invalid request URL, I am getting a BadReqest error code as 400, but not message in the response JSON like something as "Code : 400 ; Message : Invalid Request"

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=xz412e35vruepr45qjrp5lyw; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 03 May 2012 14:47:15 GMT
Content-Length: 1165

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><HTML><HEAD><STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE>
<TITLE>Request Error</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<DIV id="content">
<P class="heading1">Request Error</P>
<BR/>
<P class="intro">The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.</P>
<P class="intro"></P>
</DIV>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Instead I am getting the above in tha Raw tab in Fiddler.

Any idea why this is happening and what I can do to solve it? It's been bugging me a lot and I have tried everything but it doesn't seem to work the say it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of the WebServiceHost that I'm assuming that you're using for that service. The WebServiceHost2 from the WCF Rest Starter Kit 2 should let you specify a custom json payload for your errors by throwing WebProtocolExceptions

You can check this for more details http://www.robbagby.com/rest/effective-error-handling-with-wcf-rest/

Comment: Thanks for the help, Javi. I am using "System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" for my current application. When I try to use "Microsoft.ServiceModel.Web.WebServiceHost2Factory", my application isn't responding at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var message = ex.GetOriginalMessage();
var statusCode = (ex is MyDomainException || ex.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof (MyDomainException)))
                        ? HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                        : HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

var context = WebOperationContext.Current;

if (context == null || context.IncomingRequest.ContentType.ToLower().Contains("json"))
    throw new WebProtocolException(statusCode, statusCode.ToString(), message, null);

throw new WebProtocolException(statusCode, statusCode.ToString(), new XElement("Detail", message), false, null);
```